# Blazor WebAssembly .Net 8 WebAPI CORS Issue

Tags: cors, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have the default Blazor APP and I've modified the home page to call an API. When the API initially runs the API works fine, however after a second or two the app refreshes and I see a "TypeError: Failed to fetch". When I look at the console I see the following

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com' from origin 'https://localhost:7280' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So it appears to work while the app is being prerendered but not once fully loaded.

This is my code

BlazorApp1\program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://example.com");
        });
});

.
.

app.UseCors();
```

BlazorApp1.Client\program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient());
```

BlazorApp1.Client\Pages\Home.Razor

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

response: @resptext

@code {
    public string resptext { get; set; } = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://example.com");
            request.Headers.Add("oid", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

            try
            {
                var response = await Http.SendAsync(request);

                resptext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resptext = ex.Message;
            }
    }
}
```

With the APP running if I run Chrome disabling CORS it works fine

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\temp\chrome"
```

I think the problem is I need to add the CORS policy to the BlazorApp1.Client project but I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Did you try to change `policy.WithOrigins("https://example.com");` in `BlazorApp1\program.cs` to `policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7280");`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes already been down that route and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort this, the fact it was working initially until after the prerender suggested it was a Blazor issue. In fact the problem was with the CORS in the API I was calling. I added this to the API solution

API/program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });

.
.

app.UseCors();
```

I've removed CORS from the Blazor app and all is working fine!